# How to get Share Calendar list in Outlook

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I want to get list of Share Calendar from Outlook. My scenario is that we are three members of team namely A,B & C. A and B share calendar with C. Then C gets list of Calendar in his Outlook desktop calendar list. I want to pulled list of calendar that appear in profile C .

I used following Code

```
        Outlook.NameSpace oNs = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Outlook.Recipient oRep = oNs.CreateRecipient(account.UserName);//name of C member 
        Outlook.Folders objOutlookFolders = oNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRep, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Folders;
        //Outlook.Folders objOutlookFolders = oNs.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Folders;
        foreach (Outlook.Folder folder in objOutlookFolders)
        {
        }
```

Above code does not give list A & B calendar that shared with C. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks
Shyams

Comment: Is this a Redemption related question?

Comment: I used both redemption and Outlook interopt dll . But not getting Solution. Can any one give me working version ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder`.

Comment: I am already using that . Please see in my above code. but not giving list of calendar shared by other user to me

Comment: I am getting do you know I am getting Resource "https://<domain name>/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml" not found
Error in WinHttpSendRequest(autodiscover.buildingchampions.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml): ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT
HTTP error 401 from https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
Server respose:

Error in WinHttpSendRequest(mail.<domainname>/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml): ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT
GetAutodiscoverForEmailAddress: There are no autodiscover DNS records for this address  .

Comment: That is a Redemption error. 401 means the creadentials are wrogn or are nto specified when Redemption is trying to retrieve the autodiscover XML for that mailbox. What does Outlook Object Model return?

Comment: Outlook model return correct Value . Do I need to change Redemption version ?

Comment: You need to give Redemption the right credentials. What is your Redemption code?

Comment: if (!Globals.ThisAddIn.session.LoggedOn){               
                Globals.ThisAddIn.session.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);}try{
         RDOFolder olCalendarFolder = Globals.ThisAddIn.session.GetSharedDefaultFolder("shyams.shah", rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar) as RDOFolder;             
                
              foreach (RDOFolder childCalendar olCalendarFolder.Folders)
                {
                   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }